# Check the value in db and if it is already set to 1 it will trigger the error message

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

My Database

DBName: users, Table Name: referrals
Columns:

```
taken, email, inviteCode
```

I dont know what is the correct code to check if the value of data in taken is **"1" for used** and **"0" for not used** if i enter the invite code which is already have a value of "1" in **taken column** it will trigger the "Already Used Code" Message.

register.php

```
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    $inviteCode = ($_POST['inviteCode']);
    if (empty($_POST['inviteCode'])) {
        header("Location: index.php/0");
        exit();
    } 
    $rs_check = mysqli_query("SELECT * from referrals 
                            WHERE inviteCode='$invite_code' 
                            AND `taken` = '0'"); 
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($rs_check);
    // Match row found with more than 0 results  - the code is invalid. 
    if ( $num <= 0) { 
        $err7 = "Invite code is invalid";
    } else {
        $inviteCode = $_POST['inviteCode'];
    }
    if(empty($err7)) {
        $rs_check_update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE referrals SET taken='1' WHERE inviteCode='$inviteCode'");
        header("Location: index.php/1");
        exit;
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
include ('register.php');
?>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">  
       <div class="form-email">
       <p>   
<?php if(isset($_GET["result"]) && $_GET["result"]=="1") { ?>
        <p>Code Success</p>
<?php } ?>
        </p>
        <p>    
<?php if(isset($_GET["result"]) && $_GET["result"]=="2") { ?>
        <p>Code Already Used</p>
<?php } ?>
        </p>
        <p>    
<?php if(isset($_GET["result"]) && $_GET["result"]=="0") { ?>
        <p>Please Input A Code</p>
<?php } ?>
        </p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Invite Code" name="inviteCode" />
        </div>
        <div class="submit3">
           <input type="submit" value="Invite" name="Register" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

and also i have a problem if the code is already changed the value of taken to "1" if i submit it twice i still got the message "Code Success"

Comment: Where do you define `$err7`?

Comment: @alex55132 i dont know xD i just copy this code somewhere here it still works also :D im just new in php

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087281/php-mysql-invitation-code-for-registration-form i still dont understand how his $err7 works :(

Comment: My guess is it does not work. It does not look like you create a variable called `$err7`  anywhere in this code that you have shown us

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right, show us where do you define `$err7`. It has to be somewhere because it doesn't give any error isn't it?

Comment: Come to that..... I dont see where `$_GET["result"]` comes into this either

Comment: I re edit my code i put the $err7 sorry for my bad code and also i use $_GET["result"] to print the message in the same page using the header and also i RewriteEngine for that result to remove the query param in url

Comment: any help please?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to correct register.php, I would do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    if(!isset($_POST['inviteCode']) || $_POST['inviteCode'] == ''){
      // If inviteCode is not set or empty
      header('Location: index.php/0');
    } else {
      // Use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent SQL injection.
      // Sending raw user input to your database is very dangerous.
      // Also, you don't need to assign a variable to the same thing multiple times.
      $invite_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inviteCode']);
      $rs_query = 'SELECT * FROM `referrals` WHERE `inviteCode` = "'.$invite_code.'"';
      $res = mysqli_query($conn, $rs_query);
      $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

      if($num <= 0){
        $err7 = 'Invite code is invalid.';
        // You probably want to do something -like printing it- with this error.
        // Just attaching it to a variable will display nothing to the user.
      } else if($num == 1){
        if($res->taken == 0){
          $rs_check_update = 'UPDATE `referrals` SET `taken` = 1 WHERE `inviteCode` = "'.$inviteCode.'"';
          if(mysqli_query($conn,$rs_check_update)){
            // If the update query is successful.
            header('Location: index.php/1');
          } else {
            // Error handling if the update query fails.
          }
        } else {
          // taken column in db is not 0
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help i have a question where do i input the "already used code" message if the data of the invite code in taken column is already set to 1

Comment: @EllsowrthSanders I have edited the code accordingly, let me know if you get an error or something, I haven't tested the code on a server.

Comment: it did not updating the value of taken to 1 but i redirect to index.php/1

Comment: It shouldn't redirect to index.php/1 if the query fails. That's why we put the mysqli_query in an if statement. Make sure the query is correct for your database.